# Combining bottom navigation bar and a Drawer

Tags: flutter, navigation, navigation-drawer

**context**: my app navigation relies on one screen with a scaffold and a BottomNavigationBar containing BottomNavigationBarItems. If you click an item, its index dertermines which widget is picked from a list to serve as body for the scaffold. (Code below)

**problem**: I'd also like to add a Drawer to the scaffold that can also be used for navigation. I know how to add a drawer, but I don't know how to connect items in there with my navigation.

**solution I can see**:

I could try writing my own function that determines the index of whatever I click in the drawer and sets my page selection to that index. I don't want to reinvent the wheel though; Is there anything like the combination of "BottomNavigationBar + BottomNavigationBarItems" I could place in the drawer? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

*EDIT: I can also just add a list of items wrapped in individual GestureDetectors and call _selectPage() with a hard coded index ... but that does feel clumsy.*

Shortened code of the screen for the tabbed navigation:

```
class _TabsScreenState extends State<TabsScreen> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  late List<Widget> _pages;
  late Timer timer;
  int _selectedPageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _pages = [
      HomeScreen(),
      FavoritesScreen(),
      LookBackScreen(),
      InfoScreen(),
    ];}

void _selectPage(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedPageIndex = index;
      });
    }

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      //
      body: _pages[_selectedPageIndex],
      //
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _selectPage,
        currentIndex: _selectedPageIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          //home
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home, color: customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.home, color: customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
          //favorite
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon:
                Icon(Icons.favorite, color: customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
          //loockback
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.bar_chart, color: customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon:
                Icon(Icons.bar_chart, color: customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
          //info & support
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.info, color: customColorScheme['Icon 1']),
            activeIcon: Icon(Icons.info, color: customColorScheme['Icon 2']),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: am also facing the same issue... @Joe did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own class DrawerNavItem that comes wrapped in a GestureDetector and receives a pointer to _selectPage(), the icon they should have, the label text and, of course, the index of the page the item should connect to.. The drawer itself is a column listing those DrawrNavItems. As a side note: You cannot use this method to add additionall pages to the list _pages and make them accessible in the drawer. The BottomNavigationBar widget asserts that the list only contains as many items as displayed in the bottom bar.

Comment: Another note: I had to fight the BottomNavigationBar widet and the BottomNAvigationBarItem widget A LOT! If you want to do anything that is even a bit out of the ordinary in terms of looks or functionality, I'd advice to also create a custom bottom bar from the get go.

Comment: wooow this is alot i am not sure i follow.. but also tried to find a work round by passing the index into the tabsMenu page eg ( tabspage(selectedIndex:0)  and activate the route like  :  Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TabsPage(selectedIndex: 3)),
                              );

Comment: So I've taken over a project using Flutter and i started running into this issue as well. It seems like there is no "off the shelf" ready functionality for this. I wanted to make sure i was on the right path with wrapping around the bottomNavigationBar state.
Please @ me if you do find a more standard method as you usually shouldn't deviate to far from standards in the application shell.